# Python Spyder- Horizontal scrollbar in IPython console hiding the last line

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

When the Spyder console has displayed output too wide to view, it adds a horizontal scroll bar to the bottom. This scrollbar hides the last command line of the console, and it seems I am unable to scroll down further. It's a very minor issue but it's annoying the hell out of me.

I recorded my screen to show the issue: https://youtu.be/WYuA6Zssges

Reproduce the issue:

1. Plot a large figure like `fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))`
2. Try to type a new command
3. When you can't see the command you type, try to scroll down

Versions:

- Spyder version: 4.0.1
- Python version: 3.7.6
- Qt version:  5.9.7
- PyQt version: 4.6.0
- IPython verion: 7.12.0
- Operating System name/version: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This looks like a bug. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues), so we don't forget to address it in the future.

Comment: In my case, no horizontal scroll bar appears making the string wrap which is difficult to read.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba still having the same issue on Spyder 5.4.1. I will open the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone as I had the same bug when writing my code file and the horizontal bar would always hide the last line of code. It's not fixed as I hoped too but I works wonders, just right click on the code file and select the "zoom out" option (⌘- on mac) and you'll be able to code normally